# Has anyone heard anything about Mono and .NET 4 bytecode support?

Tags: .net-framework, mono-framework

As you know, Microsoft has released .NET 4, which compiles to different bytecode than .NET 2 (and 3, 3.5).

I know that Mono uses the same bytecode format as .NET 2, meaning that, under certain conditions, executables can targeted at .NET 2/3/3.5 can be run on Mono.

However, there are progressively more and more .NET 4 programs that are developed and released - and I have not been able to determine whether there are any plans to support .NET 4 bytecode in Mono.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a new bytecode for .NET 4.   I have no idea where you heard that, but it does not exist.

The only thing that exists are new libraries versioned at 4.0, and for that, you do need a new Mono (2.8 or 2.10) that come with the equivalent versioned libraries.

Comment: When I tried using the .NET 2 version of a tool for ComInterop, it failed on a .NET 4 library telling me that it was not a valid assembly. It was my faulty assumption that the only change that would trigger such a message would be a bytecode format change.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Mono project's [compatibility page](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility), Mono 2.8 can already run .NET 4 programs, albeit without some of the more advanced functionality.